# Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (LineString)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, error

I'm using PostGIS 2.5.2 on PostgreSQL 10, and I'm trying to build a function which would split a LineString into portions, depending on points positionned close to it. I'm getting a `Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (LineString)` error, and I can't figure out why. I've stumbled upon [this old](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/94664/142568)  answer but it's not helping me. Here's where the error comes from :

```
INSERT INTO portions_lignes(id_parcours, ordre_portion_parcours, id_arret, geom) 
VALUES(line_id, prior_point.ordre_arret_parcours, prior_point.id_arret, ST_LineSubstring(linestring, 0, ST_LineLocatePoint(linestring, current_point.geom) / 2));
```

Where `portions_lignes.geom` is a LineString geometry type, `linestring` is also a LineString, and current_point.geom is a Point geometry type.

All geometry types are in SRID 4326, my goal here is just to insert into portions_lignes a particular line_substring (using `ST_LineSubstring`) from the `linestring` parameter, which is passed to the function and declared like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitLine(
    line_id character varying,
    linestring geometry(LineString,4326)
)
```

Comment: when `ST_LineLocatePoint ... ` returns `0` as `endfraction` (i.e. closest point is the start point), `ST_LineSubstring` returns a `POINT`.

Comment: @ThingumaBob Thanks for your answer, I just noticed that in the `ST_LineSubstring` documentation.